# Django Reverse Error upon attempting to delete account

Tags: python-3.x, django, reverse

I am unsure of what went wrong but I cannot delete my own account.

I receive the following error:

Reverse for 'delete_account' with keyword arguments '{'user_id': 'testuser1'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['account/delete/(?P[^/]+)$']

NoReverseMatch at /account/2/

Views.py

```
def delete_user(request, username):

    if request.method == 'DELETE':
        try:
            user = request.user
            user.delete()
            context['msg'] = 'Bye Bye'
        except Exception as e: 
            context['msg'] = 'Something went wrong!'

    else:
        context['msg'] = 'Request method should be "DELETE"!'

    return render(request, 'HomeFeed/snippets/home.html', context=context)
```

urls.py

```
from account.views import (
    delete_user,
)

 path('delete/<username>', delete_user, name='delete_account'),
```

account.html

```
      <a class="mt-4 btn btn-danger deleteaccount" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete your account')" href="{% url 'account:delete_account'  user_id=request.user.username %}">Delete Account</a>
```

traceback

```
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 443, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 90, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 673, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'delete_account' with keyword arguments '{'user_id': 'testuser1'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['account/delete/(?P<username>[^/]+)$']
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if my answer would be correct, but you can give it a try.

```
<a class="mt-4 btn btn-danger deleteaccount" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete your account')" href="{% url 'account:delete_account'  user_id=request.user.username %}">Delete Account</a>
```

Change the `user_id=request.user.username` to either `username=request.user.username` or simply remove the first part `request.user.username`

It should work according to me. If not do let me know.

**EDIT**

you must change your code from

```
        try:
            user = request.user #this line
            user.delete()
            context['msg'] = 'Bye Bye'
        except Exception as e: 
            context['msg'] = 'Something went wrong!'
```

to

````
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username = request.user.username) # alternatively you could do ```User.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk)``` 
            user.delete()
            context['msg'] = 'Bye Bye'
        except Exception as e: 
            context['msg'] = 'Something went wrong!'
````

Comment: Hi rajat, thanks for the reply. The error is not gone but the account was not deleted

Comment: i was simply directed to the homepage

Comment: i will include my models.py code inside if it helps

Comment: i believe i might have accidentally made it such that only superusers can delete account? I'm not very sure how i can modify it as im still only a beginner, could you advise :)

Comment: @leung2 I am sorry, can't take a zoom class for you.... as you mentioned the error has been resolved but you are taken to the homepage without the user being deleted, that is because of the statement ```return render(request, 'HomeFeed/snippets/home.html', context=context)``` Could you tell me what was the output from ```context['msg']```?      Was it ```bye bye``` or ```something went wrong```?

Comment: Checkout the edit I made to my answer, let me know if it worked or not.

Comment: Hi rajat, it doesn't work. I also did not see the exception messages bye bye or something went wrong. it just directed me back to the homepage